# Android deep link into Instagram app

Tags: android, instagram, deep-linking

Instagram has published url schemes for iOS deep linking, but they haven't created documentation for Android.

Is there a way to deep link into the instagram app on Android to go to particular places in the Instagram app, such as specific posts in Instagram

From a technical perspective, this should have been included in Instagram's Android app and documentation many years ago, but I am not aware of it

There may be some hack way to achieve the same result that people have figured out, so any insight is appreciated.

My instagram app does not have comment access granted from Instagram, and has been denied this particular functionality so sending a comment via API is not an option and I would prefer the user opened the instagram app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instagram has registered urls on Android. When you try opening an instagram link it will prompt the user and ask them what app they want to use to handle the url. Choices will probably include various browsers, and the instagram app. When the user selects "always" and picks instagram to handle the url, it will use instagram as the default handler for `instagram.com` urls from then on.

Basically, you don't need to worry about it. It just works.

Comment: What are the registered urls? I would like to concatenate a string to take the user directly to a particular post within instagram. To clarify, I have information about instagram comments and some information about particular posts, but I will need to construct an instagram link for the IG app to interpret it properly

Comment: I see now, thanks! my situation still requires me to reconstruct the url to make this work but I might be able to figure this out

Answer (score 5):

You can directly open app with specific user name:

`instagram://user?username=$instagramPageName`

Answer (score 1):

With bellow link you can access to Instagram directly in android:

`intent://instagram.com/_u/ebadgh/#Intent;package=com.instagram.android;scheme=https;end`

You must replace `ebadgh` with your username

Comment: Is that goint the open the Instagram app with the given user account if among multiple logged in accounts in the app?

Answer (score -1):

It seems you want to link to a specific photo on a specific user's Instagram feed.

Using the [media endpoints](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/), use `getString("link")` when parsing the jsonArray at the index for the jsonObject containing the "image" and "comment".

Comment: I apologize about not following the correct way to post answers.