# What is the best option to create share button? (react)

Tags: reactjs, share, social-media

I saw a lot of option in order to create share interaction with users:

- Web share API: https://www.w3.org/TR/web-share/#sharedata-dictionary
  It seems compatible with Progressive-Web-App, but it's not well supported by firefox (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#browser_compatibility)
- Simple Sharer: https://reactjsexample.com/a-javascript-framework-to-share-url-to-social-media-sites-like-facebook-twitter-reddit-whastapp/
  If I understood well, it doesn't work for mobile, am I right?
- react-share: https://reactjsexample.com/social-media-share-buttons-and-share-counts-for-react/
  Seems to work on every browser, but I don't know if it's PWA-friendly. Seems to be the best option, but I'm not sure... The last update was 1 year ago (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-share) so maybe it will not be maintained through times...

What do you use for your app? What do you recommand?
Do you know better alternatives?

My need for the App is to share URL through social media or mail/text or ??? etc. No file in theory. And I'd like to have adapted preview on social media when the user share something.

Answer (score 0):

I have used react-share personally and it was unable to open some of the apps in mobile like whatsapp, etc.

*The workaround is **deep-links**.*

if user is using a smartphone or a tablet (we can easily get this using `navigator.userAgent`) then you can use the app based deep-links otherwise the traditional way in which you can redirect user to a new web page.
Some of the examples:

- Whatsapp: https://faq.whatsapp.com/563219570998715/?locale=en_US
- Instagram: Answer is already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479656/android-deep-link-into-instagram-app)

**NOTE**: deep-link works if the user has installed the application on desktop as well (never tried for macOS but for windows and ubuntu it works)

#### After edit:

You can use `mailto:` in `href` while writing `<a .../>`.
example:

```html
<a href="mailto:youremail@domain.com?subject=sharing%20link&body=I%20am%20sharing%20a%20link:%20https://google.com">Share this link</a>
```

For more reference about mailto please visit this MDN doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href